# Oracle: guaranteeing unmodified database state with queries?

Tags: oracle, select

If the first word of a SQL statement is either WITH or SELECT, is the statement guaranteed not to change the state of the database?  i.e. is this loop "safe"?

```
read SQL string
if string begins with SELECT or WITH
    process string
else
    error, do not execute
```

If the answer is no, what string(s) would allow data to be modified?

(note that this is a very specific question and not a request for general advice regarding database security.)

Comment: With 12c, `WITH` can include a procedure definition, so it won't be safe either: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702

Comment: I think the proper way to do this is using the utilities Oracle supplies for this purpose , e.g. privileges, views.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible for a SELECT statement to modify the database, for example:

- `select mysequence.nextval` increments a sequence
- `select myfunction` executes a PL/SQL function which could have any sort of side effects

The last point is a bit of a corner case since it only works with autonomous transactions, otherwise errors such as

```
ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query
ORA-14552: cannot perform a DDL, commit or rollback inside a query or DML
```

are returned:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> create table t1 (x number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values (42);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from t1;

         X
----------
        42

SQL> create or replace function f1 return varchar2 is
   pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
   execute immediate 'truncate table t1';
   return 'Table t1 truncated';
end f1;
/
  2    3    4    5    6    7
Function created.

SQL> select f1 from dual;

F1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Table t1 truncated

SQL> select * from t1;

no rows selected
```

Comment: I don't think you can call a function in a SELECT statement that changes the database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I have expanded my answer

Comment: Ah, right. I wasn't thinking of autonomous transactions.